# Why is my subdomain redirecting to my main domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, subdomain, amazon-lightsail

I have a subdomain `https://app.freewebcart.com`

example -- open this link `https://app.freewebcart.com` then click any of the post that post redirect to main domain

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com\$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app\.mydomain\.com\$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomai.com./$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. External links are allowed here, but only when the question also includes all of the relevant code and information. This is because links can break or change over time and make the question invalid and unhelpful to future users. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and a how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) As well as making your question meet the guidelines, it also helps us to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your wordpress install is pointing to the main URL via `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME`. Have a look at this website with instructions on how to check and make the relevant changes.

Reference: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/